# Tag ember-cp-validation needs plural

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[ember-cp-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember-cp-validation) should be [ember-cp-validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember-cp-validations):

https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations/

Could a mod rename it for me please?